# Flask SQLAlchemy - How to Query DB for objects Matching Attributes of Related Object?

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

```
from app import db


terpenes = db.Table('tags', 
                    db.Column(
                        'terpene_id', db.Integer, 
                        db.ForeignKey('terpene.id'), 
                        primary_key=True
                    ),
                    db.Column(
                        'strain_id', db.Integer, 
                        db.ForeignKey('strain.id'), 
                        primary_key=True
                    )
                    )


class Compound(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(96), nullable=False)
    percent_concentration = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=10, scale=20), nullable=True)
    terpenes = db.relationship('Terpene', backref='compound', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Compound {self.name} @{self.percent_concentration}%>'.format(self.name, self.percent_concentration)


class Terpene(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    compound_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('compound.id'), nullable=False)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'compound_id': self.compound.name
        }

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Terpene %r>' % self.compound.name


class Strain(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(96), unique=True, nullable=False)
    terpenes = db.relationship('Terpene', secondary=terpenes, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('strains', lazy=True))

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            'terpenes': self.serialize_many2many,
        }

    @property
    def serialize_many2many(self):
        return [i.serialize for i in self.terpenes]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Strain %r>' % self.name
```

I have a Flask application where I have a simple Strain object with a many-to-many field set to another Object, Terpene.

Each Terpene has a FK field to another object, Compound.

Each Strain has 5 terpenes.

I want to select a Strain and have query the database with the ORM to retrieve any other Strains which have at least 3 matching terpenes to the Strain selected.

How do I implement the query part of this with the ORM?

Example: Strain "A" -linalool -myrcene -caryophyllene -pinene -limonene

Strains queried with ORM to be returned (which have at-least 3 of the terpenes in Strain "A")

Strain "B" -linalool -myrcene -caryophyllene -geraninol -carene

Strain "c" -caryophyllene -pinene -limonene -geraninol -carene

Answer (score 1):

Start by selecting the join of strain, terpene, and compound. Then filter by A's terpenes, group by strain, and finally check that the group has at least 3 matches:

```
In [19]: strain_a_terpenes = db.session.query(Compound.name).\
    ...:     join("terpenes", "strains").\
    ...:     filter(Strain.name == "A").\
    ...:     subquery()
    ...: 

In [20]: db.session.query(Strain).\
    ...:     join("terpenes", "compound").\
    ...:     filter(Compound.name.in_(strain_a_terpenes)).\
    ...:     group_by(Strain.id).\
    ...:     having(db.func.count() >= 3).\
    ...:     all()
```